# Recyclerview will not save changed items for first and last data position

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Helo guys got a final issue with my Recycler and here is the thing,

when i click the buttons the respective listener will change the button color and set the enabled to false, this works perfectly and in a large run of data let say from 0 to 99 the view from 1 to 98 will keep the button color and the enabled set to false but the positions 0 and 99 will not.. gonna paste the adapter and will apreciate if any of you guys could help find what the problem is..  or if i need to change some recyclerview setting that I dont know of.. anyways thanks in advance for the help.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>  {

private ArrayList<Comanda> list_comandas;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public MyAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<Comanda> list_comandas)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.list_comandas = list_comandas;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return list_comandas.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    Comanda comanda = list_comandas.get(position);

    holder.setData(comanda);

    for (final Button be : holder.Articulos)
    {
        be.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                be.setEnabled(false);
                be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.cboff, null));
                mostrarMensaje("Plato Listo " + be.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    holder.btn_cerrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            removeItem(holder.getLayoutPosition());
        }
    });
}

private void mostrarMensaje(String mensaje)
{
    Toast.makeText(inflater.getContext(), mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void removeItem(int position) {
    list_comandas.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public void addItem(int position, Comanda comanda) {
    list_comandas.add(position, comanda);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    //definicioin de variables

    List<Button> Articulos;

    private TextView txt_comanda;
    private TextView txt_mesa;
    private TextView tid;
    private TextView torden;
    private TextView te;

    String tag="";

    private Button btn_cerrar;
    private Button be;
    private LinearLayout le;
    private LinearLayout lyocomanda;
    private LinearLayout elpadre;


    public  int getScreenWidth() {
        return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    }

    private MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        //inicializacion de controles

        elpadre = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.elpadre);

        lyocomanda = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.lyocomanda);

        txt_comanda = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_comanda);

        txt_mesa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_mesa);

        tid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tid);

        torden = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.torden);

        btn_cerrar = (Button) itemView.findViewWithTag("primal");

        Articulos = new ArrayList<Button>();

    }

   void setData(Comanda comanda) {

        String cadena= comanda.getOrden();

        Integer tope = cadena.length();

        Boolean tijera_categoria = false;
        Boolean tijera_articulo = true;
        Boolean tijera_contorno = true;
        Boolean tijera_cambio = true;
        Boolean creador = false;

        Integer indisup;
        Integer indiin = 0;
        char apuntador;
        String Buscado = "";
        String Buscado_contorno = "";
        String Buscado_categoria = "";
        Integer id = -1;
        String comandero="";/////////////////////////////ACA VARIABLES DE SETEO DE DATA


       if (getAdapterPosition()<10)
       {
           comandero = "0";
       }
       else
       {
           comandero="";
       }
        txt_comanda.setText(comandero + getAdapterPosition()+ "");

        txt_mesa.setText(comanda.getMesa());

        tid.setText(comanda.get_id());     //para el proceso de PUT

        torden.setText(comanda.getOrden());//para el proceso de PUT

       int copantalla;
       int dipantalla = getScreenWidth();


       if (dipantalla < 2400){
           copantalla = 2;// smaller device
       }
       else{
           copantalla = 4;// 6.5inch device or bigger
       }

      elpadre.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(dipantalla/copantalla, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        for (int i = 0; i < tope ; i++) {

            apuntador =cadena.charAt(i);

            if (Buscado.equals("Bebidas"))
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (apuntador == '$')
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    //EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

                    if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_categoria) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            indiin = i + 1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (apuntador == '!' && !tijera_categoria) {
                        tijera_categoria = true;
                        tijera_articulo = false;
                        creador= true;
                        indisup = i;
                        id =id+1;

                        Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                        indiin = indisup + 1;

                        Buscado_categoria = Buscado;

                        tag= txt_comanda.getText().toString() + id;

                        be = new Button(inflater.getContext());
                        be.setTag(tag);
                        int idr = Integer.parseInt(tag);
                        be.setId(idr);
                        Articulos.add(be);
                    }

                    if (apuntador == '%' && !tijera_articulo) {
                        indisup = i;
                        tijera_articulo = true;
                        tijera_contorno = false; //aca viejo listener de be

                        Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);

                        indiin = indisup + 1;

                        //this.be.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);
                        if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Fondos")) {
                            be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.fondos, null));
                        }
                        if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Entradas")) {
                            be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.entradas, null));
                        }
                        if (Buscado_categoria.equals("Postres")) {
                            be.setBackgroundTintList(inflater.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.postres, null));
                        }
                        be.setText(Buscado);
                        be.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        lyocomanda.addView(be);
                    }

                    if (apuntador == '*' && !tijera_contorno) {
                        indisup = i;
                        tijera_cambio = false;

                        Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                        indiin = indisup + 1;

                        if (!Buscado.equals("")) {
                            Buscado_contorno = Buscado;
                            te = new TextView(inflater.getContext());
                            te.setText(Buscado);
                            te.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            //te.setTextSize((inflater.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.txt_size)) / 2);

                            if (creador){
                                le = new LinearLayout((inflater.getContext()));
                                creador=false;
                            }

                            le.addView(te);

                        }

                    }

                    if (apuntador == '#' && !tijera_cambio) {
                        indisup = i;
                        tijera_contorno = true;
                        tijera_cambio = true;
                        tijera_categoria = false;

                        Buscado = cadena.substring(indiin, indisup);
                        indiin = indisup + 1;

                        if (!Buscado_contorno.equals("")) {
                            le.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                            le.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                            le.setBackground(inflater.getContext().getDrawable(customborder));
                            lyocomanda.addView(le);
                        }

                    }

                }//FIN DE LA EJECUCION PRINCIPAL
            }//DEL INICIO DE EJECUCION PRINCIPAL

        }// DEL FOR

    }

}
}
```

Comment: I will suggest you to store the enabled status as a state in your viewHolder and accordingly set the button state in your `onBindViewHolder`. Follow the same pattern for `background color`. The point being , with all the recycle and stuffs and going on, it is better to take control of the state of each item rather than relying on Recyclerview. Just to add, I had similar problem with the first item and debugging realised that for the first view `onBindViewHolder` was called multiple times and it has been like that for some time.

Comment: sounds good, gonna try and report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, well I have solved the problem by increasing the RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool, it comes with a default of 5 and if your views are all even, it has no problem at all on keeping all good, however, if you have like in my case changing views, once you increase the pool from 5 to DataArray.size() you start getting trash in every view.

so as of now I have managed to save the buttons enabled state AND the colors for each view no matter the DataArray.size() with

```
 recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0,DataArray.size());
```

BUT I was getting trash in everyother view if the views were not even so I had to change another setting to be also dynamic with my data

```
 recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize(DataArray.size());
```

so now I can have the recycler working properly, hope this can help anyone..

Thanks @Dibzmania for the reply :) .. ps. oh btw @Dibzmania I tried what you told me and it didnt work BUT it got me on the right track..